# MySQL join 2 tables on non-unique column and with timestamp conditions

Tags: mysql

I have 2 MySQL Tables: "parts_revisions" and "categories_revisions". My goal is to use the revisions data in these tables to create a log that lists out all the changes made to parts and categories. Listing the changes to "parts" in one single SQL statement has proven tricky though! Here is the situation:

All entries of each table have "timestamp" columns.

Every parts_revisions entry has a "categoryId" that basically links it to the categories_revisions table. (Every part is a child of a parent category.)

All I want to do is list out all the parts_revisions, but use the human-friendly "name" column from the categories_revisions table based on the categoryId column in parts_revisions. This will make the log more readable.

The trick is that, because there are usually multiple revisions for each category within the categories_revisions table, I cannot do just one big 'ol join on the categoryId column to get the name. The categoryId column is non-unique, and "name"s may vary. What I have to do is get the **latest** category_revisions entry that has a timestamp that is **no later than** the timestamp of the part_revisions entry. In other words, we want to get the appropriate category name that was in use AT THE TIME the part revision was made.

Comment: I believe it would be easier (at least for me) to post the structure of these two tables, or even better, to build a sqlFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: @hex494D49 , yes I understand. Well depending on if I get much feedback (or don't figure it out myself), I might update the question. Thanks for the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this matches your table structure, but here's a go at it. It's a bit of an ugly subquery inside a subquery. Guessing it won't be terribly efficient

```
select part_name, 
       category,
       (select name
          from categories_revisions
         where categories_revisions.match_id = parts_revisions.category 
           and categories_revisions.timestamp = (select MAX(categories_revisions.timestamp) 
                                   from categories_revisions 
                          where categories_revisions.match_id = parts_revisions.category
                            and categories_revisions.timestamp < parts_revisions.timestamp)) as name
   from parts_revisions;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/da74e/1/0

Comment: Thanks to @hex494D49 for pointing me at SQL Fiddle. Great tool.

Comment: Jenkies Velma, we are rockin now. Yeah beats me about how efficient or not that is, but hey, it works! That's good enough for now. Thankyou. P.S. You pretty much nailed the table structures, I know my question was a little verbose. great job.

Comment: just wanted to say I will be using this code _without_ attribution to you, unless you require it.

Comment: I don't require it. It was a fun puzzle for a Friday afternoon. Glad it worked for you.